# Dynamic insertion of variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of eigenvectors of a given matrix. I need to programmatically modify this list by multiplying each vector by a variable #i, e.g.

```
{#1 {1,0,1}, #2 {1,0,-1}, #3 {0,1,0}}
```

So that I can go on to extremize various functions of the vectors with respect to the #i. This it to be applied to a list of vectors of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a function of an arbitrary number of variables:

```
mult[list_] = Function[Null, MapThread[Times, {{##}, list}]];
```

Then apply it as follows:

```
l = { {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};

mult[l][a, b, c]

(* ==> {{a, 0, a}, {b, 0, -b}, {0, c, 0}} *)
```

The number of variables in `[a, b, c]` must of course match the number of vectors in `l`.

The above example can also be broken up like this:

```
m = mult[l];

m[a, b, c]

(* ==> {{a, 0, a}, {b, 0, -b}, {0, c, 0}} *)
```

Here `m` is defined as a function and can be called as such.

The same thing can also be achieved with the definition

```
mult[list_] := MapThread[Times, {{##}, list}] &
```

The above is based on my interpretation that the goal was a function that accepts an arbitrary number of variables matching the input list.

If the goal is to generate an expression and not a function, then you'd have to provide a naming scheme for the generated variables. The cleanest would be to name them as components of an `Array` with some base name:

```
Clear[mult]

mult[list_][name_Symbol] := Table[name[i] list[[i]], {i, Length[list]}]

mult[l][A]

(* ==> {{A[1], 0, A[1]}, {A[2], 0, -A[2]}, {0, A[3], 0}} *)
```

Comment: I would like the program to determine the number of variables needed as well.

Comment: I don't understand what output you need. The symbols `#i` are slots of a function, they aren't themselves variable names. Do you want the function to generate variable names for you?

Comment: I can use the #i as variables just as well.

Comment: No, you can't - they are protected symbols. I'll add another approach that you may be looking for.

Comment: As I see it, using an undisclosed number of alphanumeric (or combination of alphanumeric) characters as variables may run into problems with previously defined constants.

Comment: If you want to extremize an expression with respect to some variables, you have to decide what to call the variables. There's no way around that.

Comment: #1 vec0[[1]] + #2 vec0[[2]] + #3 vec0[[3]];                 Solve[{-(#1/Sqrt[2]) - #2/Sqrt[2] + #3/Sqrt[3], #2/Sqrt[
    2] + #3/Sqrt[3], #1/Sqrt[2] + #3/Sqrt[3]} == {1, 0, 0}]

 {{#1 -> -(Sqrt[2]/3), #2 -> -(Sqrt[2]/3), #3 -> 1/Sqrt[3]}}

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to gather your eigenvectors in a matrix and then define your collection of variables using Array. Your desired output form is then an outer product:

```
matEig = {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};
vars = Array[x, First@Dimensions@matEig];
Diagonal@Outer[Times, matEig, vars, 1]
```

With matEig defined as your matrix above, this returns

```
{{x[1], 0, x[1]}, {x[2], 0, -x[2]}, {0, x[3], 0}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your eigenvectors are in `ev` and your multipliers are in `m`,

```
ev = { {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};
m = {2, 3, 4};
```

then with a little algebra

```
DiagonalMatrix[m].ev
(* {{2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, -3}, {0, 4, 0}} *)
```

`DiagonalMatrix` creates a matrix with `m` on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere and `.` is regular matrix multiplication.

If `Length[ev]` is very large then you can use `SparseArray` instead.

```
SparseArray[MapIndexed[{First@#2, First@#2} -> #1 &, m]].ev
(* {{2, 0, 2}, {3, 0, -3}, {0, 4, 0}} *)
```

This will save memory.

Hope this helps.